# Defining metric/metric space and normed vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I need help on defining these terms!

(a) Let X be a metric space and d the metric. Define

˜d(x, y) = min{1, d(x, y)}, x, y ∈ X,

Show that ˜d is a metric on X and ˜d(x, y) ≤ 1 for all x, y ∈ X.

(b) Let X be a normed vector space, X ≠ {0}. Define

φ(x) = min{1, ||x||}, x ∈ X.

---

a) I know that: d(x,y) = d(y,x) and d(x,z) ≤ d(x,y) + d(y,z) also d is real-valued, non-negative, and finite. From what I understand ~d is a subset of X and therefore, a subset of d(x,y), so ~d is a metric on X? I'm not really sure what to do on the ~d(x,y) ≤ part.

b) Do I just follow the definition of norm here (showing they are subadditive and homogenous, and don't equal zero) and input x as 1 and x as ||x|| ?

I'm also curious: Is there anyway φ is not homogenous though?

Comment: For the $\leq 1$ take a moment to think about what minimum means and try not to overthink this.

Answer (score 1):

A **metric space** is a set $X$ along with a **metric** $d$ on the set; i.e. a function $d : X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$. The metric space $(X,d)$ is often abbreviated to just $X$. The metric $d$ needs to satisfy symmetry, positive definiteness, and the triangle inequality.

For example, the normal absolute value $|x-y|$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}$: $|x-y| = |y-x|, |x-y| \geq 0$ with equality iff $x=y$, and $|x-y| + |y-z| \geq |x-z|$.

For part (a), you need to show the function $\sim d(x,y) = \min\{1, d(x,y)\}$ satisfies the properties I mentioned.

*Hint: since $d$ is a metric on $X$, for any $x, y, z \in X$, $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ (symmetry), $d(x,y) \geq 0$ with equality iff $x = y$ (positive definiteness), and $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$ (triangle inequality).*

I'm not sure what the question is in part (b); it may have been cut off.